# If $ E[|X|^k]<\infty$ for all $k \in [a,b]$ then $f(k)=E[|X|^k]$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Is following property of absolute moments true?

> If $ E[|X|^k]<\infty$ for all $k \in [a,b]$ then $f(k)=E[|X|^k]$ is
>   continuous  on $[a,b]$.

I think it should be true.  It doesn't seem possible that for $f(k)$ is discontinuous.

Note that if $X$ is bounded and $k>0$  then the result follows by the dominated convergence theorem since
\begin{align}
|X|^{k_n} \le A^{k_n} \le B
\end{align}
the last inequality follows since $k_n$ is convergence sequence it must be bounded.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_{k_n \to k_0} E[|X|^{k_n}]= E[ \lim_{k_n \to k_0} |X|^{k_n}]= E[  |X|^{k_0}]
\end{align}

I wanted to also say that I very much interested in cases when $k$ is negative.

Comment: Assuming $a>0$, it is true if the random variable is bounded, so $|X| \leq B$  for some finite constant $B$.  Can you use Jensen's inequality to prove it?

Comment: If you can get that proof, then Holder's inequality can give you a more general statement in the case when appropriate expectations are finite.

Comment: In the bounded case, we can use dominated convergence theorem to show that this continuous.  Also, how do you propose to do this with Holders? Do you want to insert an indicator function into the expectation?

Comment: Perhaps you can show how you would use dominated convergence theorem to prove? Also, can you get any obvious counter-examples when $X$ is not bounded?

Comment: @Michael "Assuming a>0, it is true if the random variable is bounded" Sorry but no.

Comment: @Michael I added a proof using DCT. No I was not able to think of an obvious counter-example.  I actually think it holds.

Comment: Hint: Use the domination $$|X|^k\leqslant|X|^a+|X|^b$$ for every $k$ in $[a,b]$, and the continuity of the function $k\mapsto |x|^k$ on $k>0$, for every fixed $x$. The result follows by Lebesgue DCT.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I didn't know this inequality.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Did : Your "sorry but no" comment makes no sense.  Clearly extra conditions are needed here and $a>0$ is quite reasonable.

Comment: @Boby I suppose part of the question depends on if "$E[|X|^k]<\infty$ for $k \in [a,b]$" means "for some particular $k \in [a,b]$" or "for all $k \in [a,b]$."

Comment: @Michael it's for all $k$. I will edit.

Comment: @Boby : I see.  The "obvious counter-example" I had in mind was if $E[|X|^k]<\infty$ but $E[|X|^x]=\infty$ for all $x \in [k+\epsilon, b]$.  When proving something, it does not hurt to solidify special cases.  You can work out the bounded case with basic (non-measure theory) things.  Since you know a convergence theorem, the thing I was going to say (two comments later) is "why not use a more general Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem."  (but you likely thought of that yourself after using the bounded convergence theorem).

Comment: @Michael Let me expand a little my first comment then: you led the OP into several deadends (boundedness, already mentioned, but also Jensen, and nonexistent counterexamples). I see no reason why these deadends should not be mentioned as such in the OP's interest.

Comment: @Did :  The original question gave no work or thoughts and did not mention boundedness. Boby refined the question as I made comments.  _It is good if the asker figures things out on their own, and it is never a deadend to get intuition from special cases_.  I mentioned $a>0$ and boundedness to avoid distractions.  I assumed the asker would use a basic non-measure theory derivation like $$E[|X|^k]^{(k+\epsilon)/k}\leq E[|X|^{k+\epsilon}]\leq E[|X|^k]B^{\epsilon}$$  I was surprised the asker mentioned "dominated convergence” in reaction to my boundedness suggestion.

Comment: @Did : (continued)  After Boby mentioned a "dominated convergence" theorem, you can see in the comment trail that I changed my tack and suggested for Boby to give a detailed proof using that. _The asker was making significant progress, gave a proof,  and would likely have realized the LDC proof is essentially the same_.  
Then you jumped in and gave a negative comment to me and offered up LDC before the asker could even get there.

Comment: "After Boby mentioned a "dominated convergence" theorem"" vs "offered up LDC before the asker could even get there": Huh?

Comment: @Did : Boby mentioned "dominated convergence theorem."  The kind was unspecified, he actually used "bounded convergence theorem" in his proof, not "Lebesgue Dominated COnvergence Theorem."

Comment: Sorry but do you find your own arguments convincing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67257/discussion-between-michael-and-did).