# If $Z=X\cdot Y$ then $E[X^k]= \lim_{n \to k} \frac{ E[Z^n]}{ E[Y^n]}$ if $E[X^k]<\infty$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, expectation

I am curious whether the following theorem is true.

> Let $Z=X \cdot Y$  where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent positive
>   random variables. Moreover, suppose that  $E[Z^k],E[Y^k]<\infty$ for
>   all $k \in (a,\infty)$, and $E[X^k] <\infty$ for all $k \in
>  (b,\infty)$.  Then, \begin{align*} E[X^k]= \lim_{n \to k} \frac{
>  E[Z^n]}{ E[Y^n]}, \forall k \in (b,\infty). \end{align*}

First, note that we are not assuming that $a$ and $b$ are positive. In fact, the interesting case happens when $a$ and $b$ are negative.

Note that the above result is true  if $a\le b$ and $k \in (a,b)$, then by independence we have that
\begin{align*}
E[Z^k]=E[X^k] E[Y^k]  \Rightarrow  E[X^k]=\frac{E[Z^k]}{E[Y^k]}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, an interesting case is when $a>b$.  Note that in this case we can not write  $E[Z^k]=E[X^k] E[Y^k] $ as $E[Z^k],E[Y^k]=\infty$.

Let me also give you an example of $Z,X,Y$.   Take $X$ to be Rayleigh and $Y=|W|$ where $W$ is a standard normal. Then    $Z$ has an exponential distribution.

Moreover, note that

- $E[Y^k]=E[|W|^k] <\infty$ iff $k \in (-1,\infty)$,
- $E[Z^k] <\infty$ iff $k \in (-1,\infty)$,

but   $E[X^k] <\infty$ iff $k \in (-2,\infty)$.

I also wonder if continuity of $f(k)=E[X^k]$ is an important element of the proof. See this related [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476683/if-exk-infty-for-all-k-in-a-b-then-fk-exk-is-continuous-o?noredirect=1#comment5118230_2476683)